# I can't get my likehood function to work in R

Tags: r

I have a problem programming this likelihood function in R:

[image: Likelihood function]

I have managed to code the functions `h` and `lambda`. It is the sum I need to figure out, so far my attempt has been the following:

```
log.lik<-function(x){
  sigma<-x[1]; tau<-x[2]
  for(j in (1:6)){
    t<-rep(0,7)
    t[j]<- -0.5((I-j)*log((1/p[j])*sigma)-log(1+lambda1(j,sigma,tau)*sum1[j])-h_j.1(j,sigma,tau)
}
return(-0.5*sum(t))
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, since the result is too weird.

Comment: what kind of object is `x`?

Comment: x is a vector of 2 parameters: x<- c(x_1,x_2)

Comment: Close vote because no definition of `h_j.1` or `lambda` or any of the other vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about your actual problem, I'm guessing that you want to move the line

```
t<-rep(0,7)
```

out of the for loop.

Comment: hmm that actually gave a better result, at least my hessian matrix has values now. Just not sure if my parameters are correct, but thanks!